# Aplicação SE para Android problema nas tags com acentuação

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização, android-app

Ao consultar a minha actividade na aplicação da SE para Android, reparei num problema ao serem apresentadas palavras com acentuação, especificamente nas tags:

[image: Captura de Tela]

**Nota:**

Este assunto encontra-se já reportado no METÃO [nesta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223659/184576), está aqui para que utilizadores Portugueses saibam que já existe uma indicação à SE relativa ao mesmo.

---

<sup>This question exists merely to inform Portuguese users that the issue [has been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223659/184576) on meta.stackoverflow.com</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed as of version 1.0.18, thanks!